# Russian Doll caching and hiding sensitive links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

How do we hide sensitive, or user-specific links such as 'Edit' or 'Delete' button while caching views?

When using caching, you can't really use the conditionals such as:

```
<% if current_user.can? edit %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
<% end %>
```

because all viewers will be served an identical page.

Some tutorials tell me that I could use CSS as such:

```
<% if current_user.can? edit %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post), class: 'admin-link' %>
<% end %>
```

But how would I go about validating the permission to edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add that part in the caching key, like for example

```
<% cache [@post, current_user.can? :edit] do %>
  <% if current_user.can? edit %>
     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Just make sure to handle the part where the user is not logged in, you could send this in a variable from the controller, for example

```
@can_edit = user_signed_in? && current_user.can? :edit
```

Then in the view it would become

```
<% cache [@post, @can_edit] do %>
```

This way rails will generate two caches, one for those who can edit and one for those who can't, and render each for the correct users.

Comment: That seems like the best practice. Could you also tell me how you would do the same using CSS, like in the original question?

Comment: I'm not sure how a css class could handle it, the only thing it would be able to do is just hide the link, but it would be still in the html code, maybe if you link to where you got that idea i might be able to help.

Comment: Unfortunately the link will require a paid subscription. I am guessing I could use JS to check user permission and dynamically update the HTML class. But that seem kind of brittle compared to your approach.